# Javascript: help with replacing '<div>' with '<br>' of an innerHTML!

Tags: javascript, html, replace, innerhtml

I have an editable div where the user writes. As he writes, a javascript function adds the div html to a `textarea`. When the user presses SHIFT+Enter, the div gets a `<br>`. This is good.

But when the user presses Enter alone, the div gets `<div></div>` tags.

Therefore I try to make it so that when Enter is pressed, javascript scans the div's html to eliminate the `</div>` and change the `<div>` for `<br>`. The result will be that regardless of whether the user presses SHIF+Enter or Enter, the div's html will end up using only `<br>` for linebreaks.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function doStuff(e){
            if (window.event.keyCode == 13) {
                var s=document.getElementById("divv").innerHTML;
                s.replace("<div>", "<br>");
                s.replace("</div>", "");
                document.getElementById("divv").innerHTML=s;
            }
            document.getElementById("txtt").value = document.getElementById("divv").innerHTML;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div contenteditable="true" id="divv" onKeyUp=doStuff(event);">
        write here! Then press enter!
    </div>
    <textarea id="txtt" rows="30" cols="100">  
    </textarea>
</body>
```

My code doesn't work. When Enter is pressed, The textArea still shows div tags.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method does not modify the string it's called on, it *returns* a new string with the occurrences replaced.

You can do something like:

```
var divv = document.getElementById("divv");
divv.innerHTML = divv.innerHTML.replace("<div>", "<br>").replace("</div>", "");
```

Comment: Stupid me. This was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Usually browsers will have innerHTML store tags as `<DIV>` and `</DIV>` - you could try using:

```
s = s.replace(/<div>/ig,"<br>");
s = s.replace(/<\/div>/ig,"");
```

Comment: Yeah I realized replace returned the modified string instead of just changing it. But thanks for the /ig. I hadn't realized it would stop on the first  match.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you use xhtml, you must use tag "< br / >".

Also draw attention on str.replace: it replaces only once.

```
js> var x = "hello";
js> x.replace("l", "L");
heLlo
```

Make your replace implementation:

```
js> function myreplace(str, pattern, change_to) {
var s = str;
var s2 = s;
do {
   s2 = s;
   s = s.replace(pattern, change_to);
} while (s2 != s);
return s;
}
js> myreplace("helllllo", "l", "L");
heLLLLLo
```

Comment: er, i forgot about regex replace ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287970/javascript-help-with-replacing-div-with-br-of-an-innerhtml/4287999#4287999 ). Better to use it.

Comment: yeah im using regex. With /ig it won't stop on the first match. Tahnks anyway.